# Access the iOS camera roll and display the file selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on project where I need the user to take a video or select one from their camera roll. After selection, it will be shown on the page; maybe append it to a div to show it bigger.

How can I do this? Every video they select I want it to appear in the body as a list type thing and be able to scroll through out everything you selected.

A few things I took into consideration.

```
<input type="file" accept="video/*" id="cameraInput" name="cameraInput">
```

But I didn't know how to display the input.

Comment: `video.src=URL.createObjectURL(cameraInput.files[0])`

Comment: Were would I add that to the code? @dandavis

Comment: probably on input's onchange() event...

Comment: It doesn't seem to work though @dandavis

Comment: you would need a `<video id=video></video>` in your doc to use my generic example syntax.

Comment: @dandavis http://jsfiddle.net/pq9eh2wg/1/ see still nothing....

Comment: you were getting there:  http://jsfiddle.net/pq9eh2wg/3/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82135/discussion-between-nick-ayoub-and-dandavis).